# Framework 4: WebServices with new class is not recognized in the web site

Tags: asp.net, web-services, frameworks, web

1. I added this class

   [DataContract]
   public class PedidoTarjetaDesechable
   {
           [DataMember]
           public int idPedidoPapel { get; set; }
           ...

   }
2. I generated the web services.
3. I published it because I am using IIS7.
4. I updated the web reference in web site
5. In Web Site I generated the site

After doo that I dont understand why the project don't recognize the new class in website, could somebody give me some idea?

do I forget something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of investigation, I got the solution from msdn forum

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/f5a5dd6f-425f-4d88-848b-c4ae8f6cf220/issue-with-updating-service-reference-wcf

You have to do an operation to use the class in the WebSite Project